# Vanishing of Ext and Tor from Isomorphism of derived Hom with derived tensor product

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, derived-functors, derived-categories

Let $R$ be a Commutative Noetherian ring and let $\textbf{R} \text{Hom}_R(-,-)$ and $-\otimes_R^{\textbf{L}}-$ denote derived Hom and tensor product respectively.

We recall that for any $R$-modules $M,N$ we have that $$\text H_{-m}(\textbf{R} \text{Hom}_R(M,N))=\text{Ext}^m_R(M,N),\forall m\in \mathbb Z$$  and $\text H_m (M\otimes_R^{\textbf{L}}N)=\text{Tor}_m^R(M,N),\forall m\in \mathbb Z$.  So in particular , we have

$\text H_{m}(\textbf{R} \text{Hom}_R(M,N))=0,\forall m>0$ and $\text H_m (M\otimes_R^{\textbf{L}}N)=0,\forall m<0$.

Hence, am I correct in saying the following : If for $R$-modules $W,X,Y,Z$,  we have $\textbf{R} \text{Hom}_R(W,X)\cong Y\otimes_R^{\textbf{L}}Z$, then (taking suitable homologies on both sides), we get

$\text{Ext}^m_R(W,X)=\text{Tor}_m^R(Y,Z)=0,\forall m>0.$ ?

Comment: Is it $H_{-m}$ in the 4-th line equation?

Comment: @Sarkar: it's very hard to identify a specific line ... would you mind writing down the isomorphism you're asking about ?

Comment: I mean the equation $\text H_{-m}(\textbf{R} \text{Hom}_R(M,N))=\text{Ext}^m_R(M,N),\forall m\in \mathbb Z$ .

Comment: @Sarkar: yes, that is correct

Comment: Yes, this holds. Also note that this situation occurs if and only if the vanishing of Ext's and Tor's in the conclusion holds, and if additionally $\mathrm{Hom}_R(W, X) \simeq Y \otimes_R Z$. This is because complexes with unique nonzero homology group are quasi-isomorphic (i.e. isomorphic in the derived category) to their nonzero homology.